Can't manage to set up flutter local notification in the new gradle declarative plugin format
I'm trying to follow the instructions on the package page but the files on my flutter project are just written differently and I couldn't understand how to modify the instructions to my code.
The manifest.xml:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application

    android:label="hadassah_noa"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>

<!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
     https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
     https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

     In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent>
</queries>
</manifest>

The reference instructions not working and giving me error that it can't find the class.
Also in my build.gradle file, I don't have dependencies sections.
